# JAVA_HOME variable not correct when running ant from java

Tags: java, ant, javac

I want to build my code (which was written in the netbeans IDE) via ant. When I do this via the commandline I have no problems. But now I have to do it via Java. Therefore I use this code:

```
        File buildFile = new File("C:/Users/user1/Documents/project/trunk/src_java_fa2/RePestApplet/build.xml");
        Project p = new Project();
        p.setUserProperty("ant.file", buildFile.getAbsolutePath());
        p.init();
        ProjectHelper helper = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper();
        p.addReference("ant.projectHelper", helper);
        helper.parse(p, buildFile);
        p.executeTarget(p.getDefaultTarget());
```

When I execute this I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" C:\Users\user1\Documents\project\trunk\src_java_fa2\RePestApplet\nbproject\build-impl.xml:894: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\user1\Documents\project\trunk\src_java_fa2\RePestApplet\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1406: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\user1\Documents\project\trunk\src_java_fa2\RePestStyle\nbproject\build-impl.xml:926: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\user1\Documents\project\trunk\src_java_fa2\RePestStyle\nbproject\build-impl.xml:268: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\jmonkeyplatform\jdk\jre"
```

So it says that my JAVA_HOME variable is not set to the jdk. But when I check this I see:

```
set JAVA_HOME
>>> JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\jmonkeyplatform\jdk
```

Why would it think the JAVA_HOME variable is set to the jre ?

Comment: How are you executing this java program? Is it via command line or via some editor?

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` usually refers to the JRE, so in case of your JDK it should point to `C:\Program Files\jmonkeyplatform\jdk\jre` (the JRE embedded in your JDK). But it’s easier to include the `tools.jar` of your JDK in the class path, so `ant` will find the class `com.sun.tools.javac.Main` without depending on the environment variable.

Comment: @Holger added the tools.jar to my project did the trick. Feel free to add this to the answers so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message “com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath” points out, the variable `JAVA_HOME` is just used because it didn’t find the compiler class `com.sun.tools.javac.Main` on the class path.

So it’s easier to include the `tools.jar` of your JDK in the class path, so ant will find the class `com.sun.tools.javac.Main` without depending on the environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

what is the content of the XML file?

a wild guess, does the XMl file have some paths that are assigned relatively 
i.e, /bin/xyz ... and not full path?

you may want to use full  path inside the XML file , if any

Comment: the build.xml or the build-impl.xml ?

Comment: i would check both, no need to post content now, as the idea is to check full path issue

Answer (score 0):

Id add some debug output to your code -

```
p.getProperty("java.home");
```

To confirm what ant is using. If it is wrong then set it to

```
p.setProperty("java.home", "C:\\Program Files\\jmonkeyplatform\\jdk");
```

As to why this is occuring - Is your build file changing java.home?